USB起動させるLinuxを使う場合、SecureBoot有効のままで起動させるには
CrowdStrikeトラブル対応において、USB起動のLinuxで問題となるWindows側のファイルを削除したいのですが、Linuxを起動させるためにはWindows側でBIOS/UEFIに入ってSecureBootを無効にする必要があります。
SecureBootが有効のままでも起動できるようにする手法についてご存知でしたら教えていただけないでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

それができたら Secure じゃない・・・ていうか BitLocker も有効になってたりすると回復パスワードが絶対必要なんだけど、メモしてなかったら結構絶望的。

SecureBoot に対応した Linux ディストリビューションを使うといいのでは？
Fedora とか Ubuntu とか。
